# ImportError: No module named 'Crypto' on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, import

Here is the situation:

```
mymachine:Systemtest user$ pip3 install --upgrade pycrypto
Requirement already up-to-date: pycrypto in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
mymachine:Systemtest user$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/user/Private/Space/Server:/Users/user/Private/Space/Client:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
mymachine:Systemtest user$ python3 -c "import Crypto"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File: "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Is this some special Mac thing? How to make sure `python3` uses the `Crypto` module?

Answer (score 3):

`python3 -m "import Crypto"` instructs the Python interpreter to import a module named "import Crypto". To test importing the module, just pass the name itself, e.g.

```
python3 -m Crypto
```

Doing the same here produces this error:

```
python3 -m Crypto
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: No module named Crypto.__main__; 'Crypto' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

This is telling you that Crypto is installed (it found it) — however it is not a module, it is a package. `python3 -m <module>` imports the provided *module* and *attempts to execute it*. Packages cannot be run directly, so this will not work.

You can just check the import by passing the import command (as you did originally, but with `-c` option), e.g.

```
python3 -c "import Crypto"
```

Update: The issue was a broken install of an old version of `pycrypto`. Removing and re-installed it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Alex updated the answer to explain what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks, but now the error I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Crypto`. I am not joking!

Comment: @Alex can you try `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` — it looks like your `python3` and `pip3` are pointing to different versions of Python

Comment: You can force install with the same version using `python3 -m pip install pycrypto`

Comment: ['', '/Users/adietz/Private/Space/Server', '/Users/adietz/Private/Space/Client', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154407/discussion-between-alex-and-mfitzp).

Comment: Do you have another folder called `Crypto` in your path? e.g. in the folder you're trying to import from?

Answer (score 2):

With the `-m` switch, you should run `python3 -m Crypto`. No need for the import. Or run `python3 -c "import Crypto"`